# TFS Check-In Form Not Showing When I right click a SQL Server Management Studio solution and click 'Check In Now (Recursive)'

Tags: tfs, ssms

Not sure if this is the correct site to post this question on. When I used to right click and 'Check In' a Sql Server Management Studio project, the TFS check-in form would show up on the screen. It no longer shows up on the screen for me, though SQL Studio manager is disabled as if a modal window is showing. When I hit escape the missing TFS check-in form 'disappears' as then I can continue using SQL Server Management Studio.

I've tried changing from 2 monitors to a single monitor, and changing the resolution while this issue is occuring out of the thought that perhaps the form is showing off screen somewhere, and would expect the resolution/screen change to force all windows back onto the single screen, but had no luck with this. It works fine with my Visual Studio 2010 though. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've tried this before posting, though re-installing TFS MSSCCI provider fixed the issue.

[Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6)